# I have a problem about creating a window with C++

Tags: c++, winapi, window

I want to create a window with C++, but I have a problem.

This is my code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <winuser.h>

int CreateDetectWindow()
{
    MSG msg;
    WNDCLASS wndc;

    LPSTR szAppName = "Web Download";

    wndc.style = 0;
    wndc.lpfnWndProc = WNDPROC;
    wndc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wndc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wndc.hInstance = NULL;
    wndc.hIcon = NULL;
    wndc.hCursor = NULL;
    wndc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) (COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wndc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wndc.lpszClassName = szAppName;

    RegisterClass(&wndc);

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindow(szAppName,"whboy",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,CW_USEDEFAULT,
        NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);

    ShowWindow(hWnd,SW_SHOW);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    SendMessage(hWnd,WM_DEVICECHANGE,0,0);

    while(GetMessage(&msg,NULL,0,0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return 1;
}

int main(){
    CreateDetectWindow();
}
```

And error with line 9 like this:

> [Error] D:\developer\C C++\window.cpp:9: error: expected primary-expression before ';' token

I'm using Windows 10 64-bit and IDE called C-Free.

Comment: It seems that [`WNDPROC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms633573(v=vs.85)) is a type name, not an object. But I have no idea what should go there instead, WinApi is a mystery to me.

Comment: See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms633573(v%3Dvs.85)

Comment: I personally would recommend a GUI framework instead, there are [numerous ones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_widget_toolkits), though. In most cases, you not only get a far more simple way to create windows, but get platform-independent as well.

Answer (score 2):

This line is wrong:

```
wndc.lpfnWndProc = WNDPROC;
```

[`WNDPROC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms633573(v%3Dvs.85)) is a type, not a variable. `lpfnWndProc` expects a pointer to a function that matches the signature defined by `WNDPROC`, eg:

```
#include <windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK MyWindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
        ...
        case WM_DEVICECHANGE:
        {
            ...
            break;
        }
        ...
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

int CreateDetectWindow()
{
    ...
    wndc.lpfnWndProc = &MyWindowProc; 
    ...
}
```